# Setting colour of a line in a ggplot2 expression with multiple aes() arguments

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to plot a different line for each of my series in this data set:

```
example <- data.frame(xAxis = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  ValueA = c(5.5, 4.5, 4, 2.9, 2),
                  ValueB = c(5, 5.3, 5, 4.7, 4),
                  ValueC = c(4, 3.2, 3, 4, 3),
                  ValueD = c(5, 4.5, 3, 2.9, 3))
```

Following what seems like the intended usage of `geom_line` and `aes` in the ggplot2 package, I construct my graph like so:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(example, aes(x = xAxis)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = ValueA)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = ValueB)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = ValueC)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = ValueD))
```

Setting the colour argument though is creating problems. Using the following seems to label the series, but not affect the colour selection:

```
ggplot(example, aes(x = xAxis)) + 
geom_line(aes(y = ValueA, colour = "green")) + 
geom_line(aes(y = ValueB, colour = "blue")) + 
geom_line(aes(y = ValueC, colour = "yellow")) + 
geom_line(aes(y = ValueD, colour = "red"))
```

However, if I set each of them to "red", then the plot understands to set them all to "red".

```
ggplot(example, aes(x = xAxis)) + 
geom_line(aes(y = ValueA, colour = "red")) + 
geom_line(aes(y = ValueB, colour = "red")) + 
geom_line(aes(y = ValueC, colour = "red")) + 
geom_line(aes(y = ValueD, colour = "red"))
```

What have I missed? I've seen that a 'standard' answer to multiple series plots in ggplot is to also use reshape to melt the data, but I feel there should be a decent solution here without needing that.

Comment: You want to move colour outside of `aes` like this: `geom_line(aes(y = ValueA), colour = "green")`. Then, you will see the four colors.

Comment: @jazzurro, solved. If you put it in an answer I'll accept it :) Knew it had to be simple.

Comment: @DaveRGP Please take your time to read an introductory text about `ggplot`. The difference about _setting_ and _mapping_ aesthetics is central. See e.g. the first two examples [**here**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_%28ggplot2%29/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to move the colour argument outside of `aes()`. Then, you will see the four colours you specified.

```
ggplot(example, aes(x = xAxis)) + 
geom_line(aes(y = ValueA), colour = "green") + 
geom_line(aes(y = ValueB), colour = "blue") + 
geom_line(aes(y = ValueC), colour = "yellow") + 
geom_line(aes(y = ValueD), colour = "red")
```

[image]